# Spring Cloud Config Client not able to resolve placeholder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am facing an issue while trying to start Config Client with the below dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The placeholder i am trying to get is the Environment variable which will help me pick up the files from config server. E.g config-client-{ENVIRONMENT}.properties

Exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'ENVIRONMENT' in value "${ENVIRONMENT}"

Comment: Can you try the below instead? -Dspring.profiles.active=<ENVIRONMENT>. Additionally, you can have the below as well in application.yml file (please format the content) "spring: profiles: active: <ENV> include: application-${spring.profiles.active}.yml"

Comment: where does `ENVIRONMENT` get set?

Comment: you are not providing enough info.

Comment: Environment gets the value injected from the Jenkins Pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot ${ENVIRONMENT} does not come out of box.

You have two options.

1. Set ENVIRONMENT= in all application.yml files. So you can get it at run time.
2. Fetch the file config-client-${spring.profiles.active}.properties so it will get the property file as per the spring profile.

Comment: Yes i followed the approach you mentioned above and it works fine. Thank you!